# ORA-30081: invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic for the below mentioned query

Tags: oracle, sysdate

```
select LASTCHANGEDATE 
from ROH_TRANSFER 
where LASTCHANGEDATE BETWEEN to_char(sysdate,'yyyy/mm/dd') - INTERVAL '10' DAY AND to_char(sysdate,'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

For the above query, I am getting the below error:

```
where LASTCHANGEDATE BETWEEN to_char(sysdate,'yyyy/mm/dd') - INTERVAL '10' DAY AND to_char(sysdate,'yyyy/mm/dd')
                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30081: invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic
```

Please help me here in resolving this..!

Note: This is how my LASTCHANGEDATE column content looks like:

```
LASTCHANGEDATE
--------------------------------
2016/11/09 02:10:01.066
2016/11/09 18:08:09.319
```

Comment: so what is the type of column LASTCHANGEDATE?

Comment: Hi I got it, just changed the sysdate as to_char(sysdate,'yyyy/mm/dd')

Comment: But now i am stuck with arithmetic error..! let me edit my question accordingly

Comment: Updated the question..! please help

Comment: Is LASTCHANGEDATE column the VARCHAR type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you wanted to do this:

```
select LASTCHANGEDATE from ROH_TRANSFER where LASTCHANGEDATE BETWEEN to_char(sysdate - INTERVAL '10' DAY,'yyyy/mm/dd') AND to_char(sysdate,'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Comment: select LASTCHANGEDATE from BPW_RECTRANSFER where LASTCHANGEDATE BETWEEN to_char(sysdate - INTERVAL '0' DAY,'yyyy/mm/dd') AND to_char(sysdate,'yyyy/mm/dd');                                          This above query will give today's records right..!? I just made INTERVAL '0'

Comment: I think in your example it won't because it's the same as select LASTCHANGEDATE from BPW_RECTRANSFER where LASTCHANGEDATE = to_char(sysdate,'yyyy/mm/dd'); notice that subtracting INTERVAL '0' DAY has no influence

Comment: I am misunderstood for what purpose you use DATE to CHAR conversion ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert DATE to CHAR/VARCHAR before executing arithmetic operations or comparisons

So try:

```
select LASTCHANGEDATE 
  from ROH_TRANSFER 
 where LASTCHANGEDATE between sysdate - INTERVAL '10' DAY AND sysdate;
```

Or if you want to truncate current date

```
select LASTCHANGEDATE 
  from ROH_TRANSFER 
 where LASTCHANGEDATE between trunc(sysdate, 'DDD') - INTERVAL '10' DAY AND trunc(sysdate, 'DDD');
```